# MATLAB Results to HTML

Tags: matlab, reporting, publish

Is there a really awesome way to organize results in MATLAB and create a set of HTML pages of the data?

I want to take a bunch of different runs and visualize the data and results in a way that is easy for people to flip through but I was hoping to do better than starting from scratch and writing raw HTML/XML code to disk.

Comment: publish() and related might help.

Comment: there's also the [MATLAB Report Generator toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/ML_reportgenerator/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might like to take a look at the publish-to-HTML functionality in MATLAB. It's extremely easy: you just add some mark-up to the comments in a MATLAB script, click the publish button or use the `publish` command, and you get a nice HTML (or Word, PowerPoint or LaTeX) file containing the code and output of the script, with your marked up comments converted to nice paragraphs of explanatory text. Here are some links to the documentation:

[Publishing MATLAB Code](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/publishing-matlab-code.html)

[Publishing Code from the Editor (video)](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/2013a/matlab/8.1/demos/PublishingfromtheEditor_viewlet_swf.html)

and to a blog article containing three enhancements to publishing, which display data as HTML tables in your published HTML:

[HTML tables](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/10/10/html-tables/)

Hope that helps!